# form value wont reset on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

On submit I would like the form to reset to Write your comment here. Below I have

```
document.getElementById('#Comment').value='';
```

but the form value is not resetting.

```
<form action="comments.php" method="post" id="Comment">
   <input type="text" style="width: 600px" value="Write your comment here" name="Comment" maxlength="250" autocomplete="off" id="Comment"
          onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Write your comment here';}"
          onfocus="if (this.value == 'Write your comment here') {this.value = '';}" /><br>

   <input type="hidden" value="Post" name="submit" /> 

   </button>


   <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#Comment').on('submit', function(e){

    // prevent native form submission here
    e.preventDefault();

    // now do whatever you want here
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
        data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#result').html('');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
            document.getElementById('#Comment').value='';
        }
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the value reset code to your success statement?

Comment: i did that and removed the hashtag. i can't believe i made that mistake

Comment: The code in the success statement will clear the value, not set it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the hash tag, change this line:

```
document.getElementById('#Comment').value='';
```

to

```
document.getElementById('Comment').value='';
```

Above will set input elements value to '', or below

```
document.getElementById('Comment').reset();
```

will [reset the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

**EDIT:**

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but try this code below,
and alter it to your requirements, placeholder is usually a better option than handling the logic yourself like you are trying, [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) is the support for it..

```
<form action="comments.php" method="post" id="Comment">
    <input type="text" style="width: 600px" placeholder="Write your comments here..." value="" name="Comment" maxlength="250" autocomplete="off" id="txtComment" />

    <button type="submit" >Submit Me</button>
</form>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#Comment').on('submit', function (e) {

        // prevent native form submission here
        e.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
            data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#result').html('');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                document.getElementById('Comment').reset();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @michelle your form and your input element both have `id="Comment"`, id must be unique, check edited answer

Comment: I think I'm having some sort of "focus" issue with the form. If I enter text into the form and click submit it functions as intended. If I enter something into the form and press enter then I see: Write your comment here, but when I start typing it doesn't clear the form. asd would give me "Write your comment hereasd"

Comment: @michelle I have made an edit, try it out. Also, remove the complexity and make it a simple "post" then add logic as you go along and test it, this way you should find exactly where it's "breaking" or not working the way you want it too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `document.getElementById('Comment').reset();`

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing button tag `</button>`, but no opening tag. Add the button `<button type="submit">` before and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resetting the value, which could be posted as a form entry, why not use a placeholder?

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Write your comment here' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, you're using jquery. Why don't you use the jquery selector and then reset the value of your form?

```
$("#Comment").get(0).reset();
```

Note: The `get(0)` function returns the form object from the selected jquery object and you can call the `reset()` method on it.